# Why does "file:///Users/username/Library/proxy.pac" not work in MacOS?

Tags: proxy, mac-osx, http, mac, pac

I tested setting up a proxy.pac file via a web server:

```
networksetup -setautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi" "http://localhost/proxy.pac"
```

and via a file directly:

```
networksetup -setautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi" "file:///Users/username/Library/proxy.pac"
```

The web server method works (provided I arrange that the proxy.pac is served by a webserver).  The file server doesn't work.

What's the problem, fundamentally?

Motivation for the question is, I'd like to simplify and prefer to not have to run an http server.

Comment: Then why do you have a proxy.pac file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't (force) reload it.  Run the following commands:

`networksetup -setautoproxystate Wi-Fi off`

`networksetup -setautoproxystate Wi-Fi on`

Let me know how it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same issue. It seems like the `file:///` url is not supported for proxy.pac files. Sadly I have not found any source to confirm this.
The workaround I have used is to place your proxy.pac file in a dedicated folder and use the `SimpleHTTPServer` python module to serve the proxy.pac file.

On a shell (or a shell script) run:

```
mkdir proxy-pac-server
cp proxy.pac proxy-pac-server/
cd proxy-pac-server
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Then you just have to enter `http://localhost:8000/proxy.pac` in your macos settings or respectively on the shell:

```
networksetup -setautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi" "http://localhost:8000/proxy.pac"
```

I know this is probably not a simplification to just run a web server in your network but it may help others without a web server to use a proxy.pac file on macos.